# Htaccess redirect with specified source domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that is running on multiple domains (different content on different domains but there are overlaps). I'd like to permanently redirect a list of pages to new URLs, but only for a specified domain.

So I have URLs like this:
`domain1.com/some/old/uri`, `domain2.com/some/old/uri`

With 301 redirect I'd need to do this:
`Redirect 301 /some/old/uri http://www.example.com/new/uri`

My problem is that this will redirect `/some/old/uri` on all domains if it exists, but I only want it to be redirected on a specified one (only I can't put an absolute path for the source URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` rule with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?old/uri/?$ http://www.example.com/new/uri [L,R=301,NC]
```

Condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]` would make sure to execute this rule only for `domain1.com` (`www` is optional)

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thank you! I knew it should be RewriteCond, but I couldn't make it work. Now, with the help of your example it's working perfectly.